# C++ Endless Loop while recursing in a tree

Tags: c++, recursion

Working with the game "from SFML games development", I am optimizing collisions. All my entities are organized in a tree of `SceneNode`. To handle collisions, I go through all my scene nodes, check which are their collidable children and then check recursively all their children. I had messed up something because now it loops between `checkNodeCollision` and `getCollidableChildren`. 
Here is the code:

```
void SceneNode::checkSceneCollision(SceneNode& sceneGraph, std::set<Pair>& collisionPairs)
{

    checkNodeCollision(sceneGraph, collisionPairs);

    for (SceneNode* child : sceneGraph.getCollidableChildren())
    {
        checkSceneCollision(*child, collisionPairs);
    }

}

void SceneNode::checkNodeCollision(SceneNode& node, std::set<Pair>& collisionPairs)
{
    if (this != &node && collision(*this, node) && !isDestroyed() && !node.isDestroyed())
        collisionPairs.insert(std::minmax(this, &node));

    for (SceneNode* child : node.getCollidableChildren())
    {

        child->checkNodeCollision(node, collisionPairs);
    }

}

bool SceneNode::isCollidable(){
    // a node is not collidable if outside the screen or destroyed
    //return (!getBoundingRect().intersects(World::Instance()->getViewBounds()) && !isDestroyed());
    return true;
}

std::vector<SceneNode*> SceneNode::getCollidableChildren(){
    std::vector<SceneNode*> children;

    for (auto& child : mChildren){
        if (child->isCollidable()){
            SceneNode* rawChild = child.get();
            children.push_back(rawChild);
        }
    }

    return children;
}
```

Here is the code from the book

```
void SceneNode::checkSceneCollision(SceneNode& sceneGraph, std::set<Pair>& collisionPairs)
{
    checkNodeCollision(sceneGraph, collisionPairs);

    FOREACH(Ptr& child, sceneGraph.mChildren)
        checkSceneCollision(*child, collisionPairs);
}

void SceneNode::checkNodeCollision(SceneNode& node, std::set<Pair>& collisionPairs)
{
    if (this != &node && collision(*this, node) && !isDestroyed() && !node.isDestroyed())
        collisionPairs.insert(std::minmax(this, &node));

    FOREACH(Ptr& child, mChildren)
        child->checkNodeCollision(node, collisionPairs);
}
```

Also, `mChildren` is a `std::vector<Ptr>` which stores all the children of `SceneNode`. I have commented out the logic in `isCollidable` to be sure that the codes works independently from that function

Comment: have you double checked your base conditions?

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't accidentally created a cycle in the scene? Have you tested with a minimal scene?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit His question is he messed something up and wants us to figure it out.

Comment: @Jav​​​​​​​​​​ia: That is not a question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was being sarcastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change checkNodeCollision to look like this:

```
void SceneNode::checkNodeCollision(SceneNode& node, std::set<Pair>& collisionPairs)
```

{
    if (this != &node && collision(*this, node) && !isDestroyed() && !node.isDestroyed())
        collisionPairs.insert(std::minmax(this, &node));

```
for (SceneNode* child : getCollidableChildren())
{

    child->checkNodeCollision(node, collisionPairs);
}
```

}